# How to align(center) row controls?

Tags: html

I don't know how to center the row those controls whithin a contact form, can you help me out ?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
                            <hr class="Tall" />
                            <div class="row center" id="form_contact">
                            <h2 class="short" style="text-align: center">Vamos <strong>Conversar</strong> ?</h2>
                            <p style="text-align: center">Queremos conhêce-lo melhor, descobrir quais são os seus problemas de modo a podermos ajudá-lo da melhor maneira possível.</p>
                                <div class="span12" id="form_fields">                   
                                    <form action="" id="contactForm" type="post">
                                        <div class="row controls">
                                            <div class="span3 control-group">
                                                <label>Nome *</label>
                                                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="span3" name="name" id="name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span3 control-group">
                                                <label>Endereço de email *</label>
                                                <input type="email" value="" maxlength="100" class="span3" name="email" id="email">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row controls">
                                            <div class="span6 control-group">
                                                <label>Assunto</label>
                                                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="100" class="span6" name="subject" id="subject">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row controls">
                                            <div class="span6 control-group">
                                                <label>Mensagem *</label>
                                                <textarea maxlength="5000" rows="10" class="span6" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4eLefh/

Thanks
-Nuno

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you're trying to achieve? If you don't know how to describe it, can you attach some sort of visual representation? Because I don't think this is what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4eLefh/3/ (Is it?)

Comment: Hi Serlite, thanks for your reply. The text-align: center , only aligns the Labels (Nome, etc. ), it does not align the row controls (input fields). I'm trying to center all the elements inside a class=row. This is what i'm trying to accomplish [link](http://www.itthinx.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/contact-form-submission.png) . And this is the issue i'm having [link](http://i.imgur.com/DtMlYFo.png).

Comment: Would you be able to set up a demo on JSFiddle or Bootply that recreates the layout you're getting? I'm trying to do so on Bootply, but it doesn't match your image provided.

Comment: Thank you @Serlite , i've managed to accomplish it by setting the following rule:  `code` #form_fields {
  margin-left: 25%; `code`
}

Comment: All right then, good to hear you've managed to solve it on your own.